# How to show VS news channel articles in external browser?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, browser, rss

Visual Studio by default shows a "Latest News" RSS channel on its start page and the articles are shown within the program window. How can I convince Visual Studio to show the articles in an external window of my system's default browser? I could not find anything on this topic here or at MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a way to customise that particular behavior. What you can do though is go `Tools` -> `Options`, `Environment` -> `Startup`, and the URL that is used is sitting right there - you can simply whack it into your browser or your RSS reader.